# Alternative of do while loop?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, break, do-while

I came across a piece of code which runs through a method which fetches results from a query(table is having 130000 records) and is using do while loop to do this.

```
public function updateTestData()
{
    $limit = 1000;
    $offset = 0;
    $processedCount = 1;

    do {
        $idList = $this->getActiveIds($limit, $offset);

        if (array() === $idList) {
            break;
        }

        $count = count($idList);
        $this->getLogger()->log("Fetching $count ids from db..", Zend_Log::DEBUG);

        foreach ($idList as $contactId) {
            //doing few log things
            $processedCount++;
        }

        $offset = $offset + $limit;
    } while (true);
}
```

Is this the right way to do this? Or is there any better way of writing this method avoiding an infinite do while loop?
Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What you need to do to fetching 130.000 records from your table?

Comment: @Federico What does it matter?

Comment: Because if you just need to count them, then the answer is another... so, what you need to do?

Comment: I want to update data in other tables, that's why i need to go through all the ids.

Comment: You can get all your rows from one query, then use `foreach` statement if you need to go through all.

Comment: `$this->getActiveIds($limit, $offset);` this returns array of ids

Comment: It seems the data fetching is done inside `$this->getActiveIds($limit, $offset);`. That function may deliver query results in packets of 1,000. Your function does something with the data and terminates if getActiveIds does not deliver any more results.

Comment: Can't you make a `$this->getAllActiveIds()`, which recieves all the Ids, then loop on it with a `$result->fetch()` ?

Comment: @Heru-Luin I'd guess the original intent was to not fetch all data at once.

Comment: You can define the while part on account of the break condition (i.e, `while(!(array() === $idList));`); although it seems that `while(true)` + break condition delivers a better performance. At least, this was the conclusion I drawed from a set of very specific tests I did some years ago (although this was in C# rather than in PHP).

Comment: @syck That's why I didn't write `$result->fetchAll()`, just `$result->fetch()`. It's better for the memory and you only have to run one query.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a `do-while`, you can simply use `while` with the method as your condition since it will return a false condition when the array is empty. I would do the following:

```
$limit = 1000;
$offset = 0;
$processedCount = 1;

while ($idList = $this->getActiveIds($limit, $offset)) {
    $processedCount += count($idList);
    $offset += $limit;
}
```

Comment: This code does exactly the same thing than OP's code. It's just more condensed and without all the logging part.

Comment: No, its not the same as OP's code. OP's code strictly compare $idList to an empty array and CodeGodie compare it to true.

Comment: Thanks @MrFreezer yes, my code is a variation of the code OP asked (since they asked for an _"alternative way"_), but definitely not the same.